# gunicorn can't run with more than one worker

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

I have a simple websocket application, e.g `main.py`

When I try to launch it with one worker,

```
gunicorn -w 1 -k "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker" main:EchoApplication
```

There's no problem.

If I increase the `w` parameter to more than 1, e.g `-w 20`, the childs start to crash,

```
error: [Errno 48] Address already in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8100)
```

Any ideas? Attached source code

```
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketServer, WebSocketApplication, Resource
import time

class EchoApplication(WebSocketApplication):
    def on_open(self):
        print "Connection opened"

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.ws.send('Let me take a sleep')
        time.sleep(10)
        self.ws.send(message)

    def on_close(self, reason):
        print reason

WebSocketServer(
    ('127.0.0.1', 8100),
    Resource({'/': EchoApplication})
).serve_forever()
```

Comment: You can't have 20 applications running on the same port, each one needs a unique port

Comment: @iScrE4m Damn! I thought that it shares the same behaviour of apache's pre fork model.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same Port. we had this issue and took some time to figure it out.

WebSocket is tied to a port and each gunicorn will try to create the WS in that same port.